# Calculate the time after which Money doubles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I while solving a problem in banking just thought to form a formula for the time period after which money deposited in bank at a compounded interest rate @$\alpha  $ % p.a. .

Amount for compounded annually is :$$A=P[1+r]^t$$ Where t is time period in years and r is rate of interest.
Now how to calculate it?

Comment: $$A=P[1+r]^t$$  ?  If r is positive, A > P.

Comment: @oks Typo ! edited :)

Comment: Thanks, also $r$ is $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A=P[1+r]^t$$  So to find when $P$ has doubled, solve

$$2P=P[1+r]^t \\
\Rightarrow t = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln(1 + r)}.$$

$t$ (for doubling) is often approximated by the "[rule of 72](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72)" i.e. $$t \approx \frac{0.72}{r}.$$

Comment: You need parentheses around $\ln (1+r)$.  Approximating this with $r$ is reasonable.  0.72 is an approximation for $\ln 2$ which is easy to divide into.

Comment: rule of 72? and ln2=0.693...

Comment: The Rule of 72 contains two approximations:  replacing ln(2) with 0.72. and replacing ln(1+r) with r.  The value 72 cancels these two errors for r around 7.5%